# Can't properly raise exception with python socket instantiation

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to properly raise an exception when instantiating a socket in Python, but I cannot made it to work:

**sock.py**

```
import socket

def create_socket():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except OSError:
        return 'OS Error'
```

**test_sock.py**

```
import mock

from sock import create_socket

@mock.patch('socket.socket', side_effect=OSError())
def test_oserror(mock_socket):
    p = create_socket()
    assert p == 'OS Error'
```

And I end up with https://pastebin.com/N5wY59RH

Where's my error?

Comment: What's the output you get?

Comment: It's in the pastebin link at the end of my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the issue here. `OSError` is not a string. It's exception class, So your code should be like this...

**sock.py**

```
import socket

def create_socket():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
        s.listen(5)
    except OSError:
        return 'OS Error'
```

**test_sock.py**

```
import mock
from sock import create_socket

@mock.patch('socket.socket', side_effect=OSError())
def test_oserror(mock_socket):
    p = create_socket()
    assert p == OSError
```